# Python POM parser replace text

Tags: xml, python-2.7, pom.xml

xml
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8MNGp.jpg)

I need change version marked on screen.

I try:

```
with open(PathPom,'r') as f:

    tree = ET.parse(f)
    root = tree.getroot()

    for elem in root.getiterator():
        try:
        elem.text = elem.text.replace('1.4.1', '5.0.0')
        except AttributeError:
        pass

tree.write(PathPom,xml_declaration=True, method='xml')
```

All versions 1.4.1 in pom are replace, and all line in document starts with `<ns0`

**Do you have any idea how to solve it?**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 [http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>cterminal</groupId>
    <artifactId>Monitor</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.1</version>
    <packaging>lba</packaging>
    <properties>
        <lb.middlewareVersion>1.7.0</lb.middlewareVersion>
    </properties>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>lba-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${lb.middlewareVersion}</version>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-enforcer-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.4.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>enforce-maven</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>enforce</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <rules>
                                <requireMavenVersion>
                                    <message>The lba-maven-plugin requires Maven version to be at
                                        least 3.1.1!</message>
                                    <version>[3.1.1,)</version>
                                </requireMavenVersion>
                                <dependencyConvergence/>
                            </rules>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please post your XML as code-formatted text (instead of image), preferably simplified to include only the relevant element, the target `version`, and some other elements to demonstrate the problem i.e 1 or 2 elements that get replaced by your code while it should not...

Comment: Another tips: to format your code, select the code block and then click `{}` on the top of the editor or hold `CTRL+K`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To prevent `ElementTree` from adding `ns0` prefix you need to map the default namespace to empty prefix before parsing the XML. And since there is only one element to be updated, you can easily get that element using `find()` :

```
....
ET.register_namespace('', 'http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0')
tree = ET.parse(f)
root = tree.getroot()

version = root.find('{http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0}version')
version.text = '5.0.0'
....
```